# Uncomment a HTML node without using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html

In this thread: [Uncomment html code using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21848916/uncomment-html-code-using-javascript)

I found that all the solutions in the thread uses jQuery. I was just wondering how to do this in vanilla javascript without using third-party library?

This is not a duplicate question of [How do I get an HTML comment with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13363946/how-do-i-get-an-html-comment-with-javascript), that thread discussed about how to find and delete the comment node but didn't say anything about how to "uncomment" it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get an HTML comment with javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13363946/how-do-i-get-an-html-comment-with-javascript)

Comment: @Quentin Thanks, I saw his/her answer, and found it used `replaceWith` method, which is a method of jQuery object.

Comment: @Rayon It is not duplicate, the thread discussed about how to find and delete the comment node but didn't say anything about how to "uncomment" it.

Comment: I guess finding it is difficult task.. replacing it should be easier..I could be wrong though :)

Comment: Maybe not the most efficient way, but by using `.innerHTML` and a regular expression to parse it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way would be to replace all `<!-- -->` with an empty string found by `.innerHTML`.

```js
var content = document.getElementById('content');

content.innerHTML = content.innerHTML.replace('<!--', '').replace('-->', '');
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <!-- <div>Hello</div> -->
  <h1>
    Title
  </h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```js
var tr = document.querySelector('table tr');
var children = tr.childNodes;
[].slice.call(children).forEach(function(child) {
  if (child.nodeType === 8) {
    var elem = document.createElement('div');
    elem.innerHTML = child.textContent;
    tr.replaceChild( elem.childNodes[0], child );
  }
});
```

```html
<table>
   <tr>
         <td>ABCD</td>
         <td>Logic</td>
         <!-- <td>26538568</td> -->
   </tr>
</table>
```